# Probability of this die tossing experiment

Tags: probability

Do we use the formula P(a)=n subscript a/N **only** when each event in the sample space is equi-probable? So for this question,**only part b**, as each event isn't equi-probable can we or can't we use this formula? So how do we go about doing this question?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this problem is to list all the ways the desired result can occur, and calculate the probability of each.

a) There are $6!$ different orders in which the die could come up 6 different values.  The probability for each specific order is ${1\over 6}\times{1\over 6}\times{1\over 6}\times{1\over 6}\times{1\over 6}\times{1\over 6} = 6^{-6}$.  For example, the probability of getting $P(\{1,4,2,3,6,5\}) = P(\{6,5,4,3,2,1\}), etc. = 6^{-6}$.

Since no two orders can come up on the same set of tosses, the total probability is the sum: 
$$P_{unordered}(\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}) = {6!\over 6^{6}}$$

b)  There are $5!$ different orders in which $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ can come up.  The next step is to calculate the probability of each ordering:

$$
P(\{1,2,3,4,5\} = {1\over 6}\times{1\over 6}\times{1\over 6}\times{1\over 6}\times{2\over 6} = {2 \over 6^5}
$$
$$
P(\{5,4,3,2,1\} = {2\over 6}\times{1\over 6}\times{1\over 6}\times{1\over 6}\times{1\over 6} = {2 \over 6^5}
$$
$$
P(\{1,5,3,4,2\} = {1\over 6}\times{2\over 6}\times{1\over 6}\times{1\over 6}\times{1\over 6} = {2 \over 6^5}
$$

The probabilities all turn out to be the same because there is one five and four other numbers each time.  Since it is impossible for two orderings to both come up, the total probability is the sum of the individual probabilities, and since those are all the same, you can simply multiple the individual probability times the number:

$$P_{unordered}(\{1,2,3,4,5\}) = {2\times 5!\over 6^{5}}$$